# Google I/O 2011 website

Tags: javascript

How did Google make the [Google I/O 2011](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/index.html) website - the drag drop and the animation in the countdown?

Comment: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/static/js/io.js

Comment: Right click > View source. Read source and linked javascript files.

Comment: If you speak about a website as example link it: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: they use Box2d http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/

If you move the logo under the balls from counter, the balls will jump on its top too. 
As jleedev is linked too: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/static/js/io.js this is the source file that makes that happen in this case.

But it is always better first look in the source and check out what can you find out from it yourself (as I and two others done it here) and try to clone it. If something don't work then you come here, show you code and ask why it isn't working. You can learn a lot by coding yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The web developers used tool, name Box2D which runs on the java-script. Box2DJS is a JavaScript port of Box2D Physics Engine. To tell the truth, this is converted from Box2DFlashAS3_1.4.3.1 in an automatic manner. You will get complete info about the tool from the link below.

http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net